# Make White Transparent shader that is not transparent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

How can I make a slightly transparent white Transparent material in cycles, when making the Transparent shader white makes it completely transparent and invisible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mixing with another shader:

[image]

Using this node setup, the Mix factor is now your transparency slider, and the diffuse color is the color of the material. (in this case, white)

[image]

Note that using a diffuse shader as the other shader shades the material slightly. If you want a solid color, you can use an Emission shader but only when seen directly from the camera.

To do this, you can mix it with a transparent shader with the `IsCameraRay` output in the *Light Path node* (*Add node > Input > Light path node*) as the mix factor.

[image]

Seen here with a .3 mix factor:

[image]