# What is the parameter A in the RGB color

Tags: node-editor

I remark that there is a parameter ***A*** in the color RGB parameter as mentioned in the image below. What is this parameter and what is its effects on RGB color?[image].

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2261/599

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The parameter A stands for *alpha*, which is the transparency channel. An alpha value of zero represents full transparency and a value of 1.0 represents a fully opaque pixel. The RGB values are not affected by the alpha value.